# jQuery .hover() code not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-hover

I want my divs to change colour upon hovering over them, but the code is not executing even when I'm hovering. I'm not completely sure why, but I think there could possibly be an issue with the fact that I'm using a z-index on the class I want to hover over.

Html with script:

```js
$(".eventContents").hover(
  function() {
    $(".eventContents").css("background-color", "yellow");
  })


//making events square
    var cw = $('.eventContain').width();
    $('.eventContain').css({
        'height': cw + 'px'
    });
```

```css
.eventContain {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  z-index: -1;
  background-size: cover;
}
.eventContents {
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.eventContents h2 {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
.eventContents p {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="events">
  <row>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="eventContain" style="background-image:url(img/events/leaf.jpg)">
        <div class="eventContents">
          <h2 class="eventName">Title of Event</h2>
          <p>short description goes about here.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="eventContain" style="background-image:url(img/events/12.jpg)">
        <div class="eventContents">
          <h2 class="eventName">Title of Event</h2>
          <p>short description goes about here.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="eventContain" style="background-image:url(img/events/1.jpg)">
        <div class="eventContents">
          <h2 class="eventName">Title of Event</h2>
          <p>short description goes about here.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </row>

</section>
```

Here is the fiddle, the issue is more prominent here:
https://jsfiddle.net/jakexia72/x7jLp17z/#&togetherjs=os0pjD0RNr

Comment: Any errors on the browser console?

Comment: @ronnyfm none at all.

Comment: Color is changing to yellow when I execute the Run code snippet option.

Comment: Seems to work for me too.. https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/4fjn0ndb/ I think, not sure what im hovering over its all blank :P

Comment: I see that it's working too, but strangely, the hover function is not even being called when all my other code is present, even though they are unrelated. Also, could it be possible that a background image is the reason it's not working?

Comment: it's unlikely that the background-image is causing problems here, maybe it's a conflict caused by another libraries because the code you posted here is functional even tho it's a little bit messy.

Comment: It does seem to be the z-index: -1 on parent. If making it z-index: 1 it seems to work fine... https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/x7jLp17z/2/ Are you able to style the page without z-index: -1 ?

Comment: Possibly adding z-index: 2; to topnav as I think you want your content scrolling under your nav menu? https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/x7jLp17z/3/

Comment: @HastigZusammenstellen I've already tried changing the z-index, however, by doing so, it causes issues with the hamburger menu.

Comment: It is apparent that negative z-index values change the behaviour of elements, making them un-selectable (if that's a word). They become unresponsive with a negative z-index. I fixed the issue by moving the navbar code to the very bottom of the html file, so that it naturally appears on top of everything else. Problems solved! :)

Answer (score 0):

The elements are being correctly hovered and the code is getting executed I've tested it, the problem is maybe that your elements are `position:absolute;` and they're all in top of each other, also they don't have a defined `height` and it's necessary because we are talking about div elements not `img`, maybe you'd want to check out your code a little bit better.

You'll want to put a `top:0px;` to your `.eventContents` because it's hidden on top (at least for this example)

One last thing, if you want to refer to the actual hovered element, you should use `$(this)` instead of the class name because it'll execute the code for all the elements with the class and not only the hovered one.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work for me, if I understood correctly, but here's a way to hover both on and off and use `this` instead of `.eventContents` twice more..

```
$('.eventContents').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
  }, 
  function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
  }
);
```

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/4fjn0ndb/1/

Comment: Why post a fiddle instead of stack snippet? Click on "Copy Snippet to Answer" to get started.

Comment: I usually do. In this case I feel its easier to play with the code in the fiddle. The important code was posted here anyway. More to come if need be, including a possible stack snippet.

Comment: It's really strange that in my complete code, the function doesn't run at all. I put a window.alert() to test if it even ran, but it didn't.

Comment: Maybe post a fiddle with a more complete code that recreates it (they don't like it when you post too much here but in a fiddle is fine) and update your answer and someone can help you figure it out. I'll try and check back on it too :)

Comment: @HastigZusammenstellen I updated it with a fiddle, thank you so much!Here it is : https://jsfiddle.net/jakexia72/x7jLp17z/#&togetherjs=os0pjD0RNr

Answer (score 0):

The negative z-index is the reason why the hover is not working, to fix it, make sure that the z-index of the element you want to hover over is positive. To avoid affecting the top nav bar, move the nav bar to the bottom of the html code file allowing it to naturally appear on top of everything else, avoiding the need to use a negative z-index on eventContain.